# Attributes declaration in class

Tags: dart

When I define in an attribute in a class, it doesn't accept any variable without initialization the variable although that don't need initialization in all references, books and video that I learn from like this:

```dart
class Employee {
  String name = 'n', Department = 'd', city = 'c', country = 'cou';
  int age = 0;
  double salary = 10.0;

  printinfo() {
    print(
        " ${name}  ${Department}  ${city}  ${country}  ${salary}  - ${age} Years  ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify your question?

Comment: Sounds like you should follow the null safety codelab: https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like below this might help you to solve your issue.

```
class Employee {
  String name = 'n', Department = 'd', city = 'c', country = 'cou';
  int age = 0;
  double salary = 10.0;

 Employee({
        this.name,
        this.Department,
        this.city,
        this.country,
        this.age,
       this.salary,
      });

  printinfo() {
    print(
        " ${name}  ${Department}  ${city}  ${country}  ${salary}  - ${age} Years  ");
  }
}
```